# Meta Key not working for emacs in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: emacs

For example, When I press L-alt or R-alt with 'V' to move back one screen as per tutorial, it just types 'V'. I have tried super key but its not the meta key either, ctrl is working fine.

Comment: define "move back one screen" .... do you mean desktop switching with Ctrl-Alt-Arrowkey and you want to go back to previous desktop?

Comment: Use the `emacs` function `describe-key` to see what's going on. `describe-key` is bound to the key sequence `Ctrl-H K`. Type `Ctrl-H K`, then the key sequence you're interested in. Also, the function `scroll-other-buffer` is bound to the key sequence `Ctrl-Meta V`, so you should hold `Ctrl` while typing `Meta V`/